# Изменение имени ключа массива в php

Tags: массивы, php

Как изменить имя ключа в массиве php? Есть такой вариант:

```
<?php
$myArray = array('oldKey' => 'value');
$myArray['newKey'] = $myArray['oldKey'];
unset($myArray['oldKey']);
?>
```

Есть ли вариант проще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если изменить ключ это разовая операция, то проще уже не придумаешь, если её необходимо выполнять часто, то лучше написать функцию

```
function change_key($key,$new_key,&$arr,$rewrite=true){
    if(!array_key_exists($new_key,$arr) || $rewrite){
        $arr[$new_key]=$arr[$key];
        unset($arr[$key]);
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

здесь `$key` текущий ключ, `$new_key` новый ключ, `$arr` массив, `$rewrite` значит перезаписывать ли элемент массива если ключ уже существует, по умолчанию `true`, возвращает `true` в случае удачно смены ключа и `false` при неудаче.

Comment: Фактически, никакой замены ключа не происходит. Данный способ не сохраняет позицию элемента в массиве. Просто создается новый элемент в конце массива. Без сохранения позиции в целом данная операция не имеет смысла. Как и сама функция не несет в себе никакого смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Нет.

Comment: @ReinRaus, красивый график уважения :).

Comment: @exec отпуск :)

Answer (score 0):

Если это первый (нулевой) элемент массива, то можно сделать так

```
$array['newKeyName'] = array_shift($array);
```